# Wood frame door and window repair. Steps by step answers please. In Ecuador

Tags: wood, doors, windows, sanding, door-frame

These are the wood parts that have been very badly damaged by sun and water. How can i restore them to the natural color they had. Id like step by step information please. Also i am in Ecuador so some material might not available here. Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuaz8.jpg

Comment: I think I would sand it down to remove remaining finish and as much of the discoloration as possible. I'd use a power sander for the large flat areas and hand sanding for the mouldings. After that I would obtain the most weatherproof finish I could find (yacht varnish?) and apply that according to the maker's instructions. I'd remove the doors to do all this.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Sounds like an answer.

Comment: Im still a bit confused about varnish over stain. I would like to keep a natural color on it. Would i use a simple varnish?

Comment: You could certainly use pkain spar varnish, without stain. However, if the wood has been significantly bleached by the sun, the only way to get the original '"natural" color back may be to stain it, or sand it very deep indeed. Suggestion: sand it down, then apply .a bit of mineral spirits. That will show you what the wood looks like wet -- which is close to what it will look like under varnish, though spar varnish like most oil finishes will add some color. If you like itm, go ahead and varnish. If not, the mineral spirits evaporate quickly and don't raise the grain.

Answer (score -1):

One Time Wood Protector is the only worthwhile option. Expensive but goes a long way & it has an unlimited shelf life for future re-applications. You just sand the crap out of everything until there are no long wood fibers sticking out (known as feathering & is mild or surface wood rot). Then, you just paint on One Time & you're good for up to 7-years. I used the Natural finish & it does darken the wood like water, but gets 10% lighter after each year of exposure. I did a redwood 2-car garage door with it 3-years ago & no more rot & no more water wicking nor soaking, I still get gushing compliments.

Comment: Iggy, if you have any connection withthe manufacturer you should disclose it. And you should cite a few similar products if you don't want this to be interpreted as an ad.

Comment: Nope, no connection. That garage door was just the final straw. I was fed up with all of the poly's, varnishes & water-proofers wearing out in just a few years & looking so horrible that they needed a full strip & sand job to continue the loop. After a lot of research I finally found One Time & won't go back to the other literal crap. The only place I could find it was Do It Best hardware stores, my local store never heard of it & never stocked it. The store 3 counties away had it & swore by it & so far they couldn't be more right, 4- years to go but I'm now beating all of the other stuff.